# Convert Console.WriteLine into text box

Tags: c#

I checked on the net and I didn't find concrete examples for my situation...

What I want, is to have these Console.WriteLine displayed in a text box .

```
    // Show data before change
 Console.WriteLine("name before change: {0}", 
 thisDataSet.Tables["Customers"].Rows[9]["CompanyName"]);

 // Change data in Customers table, row 9, CompanyName column
 thisDataSet.Tables["Customers"].Rows[9]["CompanyName"] = "Acme, Inc.";

 // Call Update command to mark change in table
 thisAdapter.Update(thisDataSet, "Customers");

 Console.WriteLine("name after change: {0}",
 thisDataSet.Tables["Customers"].Rows[9]["CompanyName"]);
```

I tried this;

```
         string1=("name before change: {0}",
         thisDataSet.Tables["Customers"].Rows[9]["CompanyName"]);


        thisDataSet.Tables["Customers"].Rows[9]["CompanyName"] = "Acme, Inc.";
         thisAdapter.Update(thisDataSet, "Customers");

        string2=("name after change: {0}",
        thisDataSet.Tables["Customers"].Rows[9]["CompanyName"].ToString());
        thisConnection.Close();

        textBox1.Text = string1() + string2();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 string1=("name before change: {0}",
     thisDataSet.Tables["Customers"].Rows[9]["CompanyName"]);
```

should be

```
string1=string.Format("name before change: {0}",
     thisDataSet.Tables["Customers"].Rows[9]["CompanyName"]);
```

(same for string2) and

```
textBox1.Text = string1() + string2();
```

should be

```
textBox1.Text = string1 + string2;
```

Comment: Error 1 The name 'string1' does not exist in the current

Answer (score 1):

I would use `StringBuilder` and then `string.Format` for readability:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.AppendFormat("name before change: {0}",
thisDataSet.Tables["Customers"].Rows[9]["CompanyName"]);

thisDataSet.Tables["Customers"].Rows[9]["CompanyName"] = "Acme, Inc.";
thisAdapter.Update(thisDataSet, "Customers");

sb.AppendFormat("name after change: {0}",
thisDataSet.Tables["Customers"].Rows[9]["CompanyName"]);

textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: You should use `sb.AppendFormat` instead of `sb.Append(String.Format)`!

Answer (score 1):

Write to a [`StringWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx) for your text box.  It's a `TextWriter` (which the "console" is exposed as) so you can easily swap in `Console.Out` or a plain old `StringWriter` to write your messages.  In your windows application, you could then put the contents of the writer into your text box.

```
////////////////////////////////////////
// for a console application
TextWriter writer = Console.Out;

// for a windows application
TextWriter writer = new StringWriter();
////////////////////////////////////////

// Show data before change
writer.WriteLine("name before change: {0}", 
    thisDataSet.Tables["Customers"].Rows[9]["CompanyName"]);

// Change data in Customers table, row 9, CompanyName column
thisDataSet.Tables["Customers"].Rows[9]["CompanyName"] = "Acme, Inc.";

// Call Update command to mark change in table
thisAdapter.Update(thisDataSet, "Customers");

writer.WriteLine("name after change: {0}",
    thisDataSet.Tables["Customers"].Rows[9]["CompanyName"]);

////////////////////////////////////////
// for a windows application
textBox1.Text = writer.ToString();
////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that: `textBox1.Text = string.Format("name before change: {0}", thisDataSet.Tables["Customers"].Rows[9]["CompanyName"]);`
or:
`textBox1.Text = "name before change: " + thisDataSet.Tables["Customers"].Rows[9]["CompanyName"];`